# Trouble with calling Namecheap's API?

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing, terminal

I used [this tutorial](http://adminpeak.com/threads/getting-started-with-api%E2%80%99s-and-php.3889/) to make a simple PHP file that uses Namecheap's API to check the availability of domain names. I followed the tutorial exactly, so my code is:

```
<?PHP
$command = 'https://api.sandbox.namecheap.com/xml.response?ApiUser=myusername&ApiKey=myapikeyed&UserName=myusername&Command=namecheap.domains.check&ClientIp='.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'].'&DomainList=adminpeak.com,kavin12345.com';
$data = file_get_contents($command);
$xml = simplexml_load_string($data);

if( ! $xml)
    {
// Code to do when load failed.
        echo 'unable to load XML file';
    }
    else
    {
// Code to do when load successful.
foreach ($xml->CommandResponse->DomainCheckResult as $result)  {
    echo $result['Domain'].':'. $result['Available'].'<br />';
}
}
?>
```

However, when I run this in my terminal using $ php namecheap.php, I get the error message:

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /Users/MyName/Documents/NamecheapPHP/namecheap.php on line 14
```

Any ideas?

Comment: It is likely that `$xml->CommandResponse->DomainCheckResult` is null. https://www.namecheap.com/support/api/intro.aspx Look into what is returned on error. Perhaps you need to check for `$xml->getAttribute('Status')==='OK'`.

Comment: Also, I believe clientip need to be the IP of the server (in the cli, `REMOTE_ADDR` is not defined). You'll need to resolve your public ip and send that instead.